# Jquery UI datepicker beforeShowDay is repeating certain dates

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When using ui datepicker to render 12 inline calendars I have noticed that the beforeShowDay function is duplicating dates ie

```
29-01-2013 
30-01-2013 
31-01-2013 
01-02-2013 
02-02-2013 
03-02-2013 
28-01-2013 
29-01-2013 
30-01-2013 
31-01-2013 
01-02-2013 
02-02-2013 
03-02-2013 
04-02-2013
```

the calendars are being updated from a database to show booked days for holiday homes and the above behaviour is causing big problems.

This is the (stripped back) function being called:

```
    function availableDays(date)
    {

        var m = date.getMonth(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            y = date.getFullYear();

        m = pad(m + 1);
        d = pad(d);

        var dateId = d + '-' + m + '-' + y;

        console.log(dateId)
        return [false];

    }
```

I am using jquery.1.8.js and jquery-ui-1.9.1.js - has anyone else come across something like this?